# On click event backfiring after adding nested anchor tag to section element

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to create a modal of sorts to open when a `<li>` offering additional information about a topic is clicked. I created a popUpTrigger that responds to a user "click" and then gathers the provided section (and all tags nested inside) and moves it to the popUp div that then appears on the page. I've taken necessary precaution in case the section is empty in which an alert will sound. However, the alert still fires when a section is not empty (it has text and contains an additional anchor tag). I'm not sure why this is happening.

When I console log, I see the nested anchor tag is being viewed by the browser as a separate entity to the section. I've tried nesting the anchor tag further within a div element and rewriting the javascript so the html of the nested anchor tag will be evaluated accordingly as part of the section but all to no avail. This backfiring only occurs when an additional anchor tag is included in the section element of the HTML.

HTML

```
<li id="card">
   <a class="popUpTrigger" href="#">
      Get a Library Card

      <section class="hide">
          <h6> How to Obtain a Library Card:</h6>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <a href="https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/858998_1fae2b5d06fa41a3ba3fcb493b349d19.pdf">
             <img src="imgs/LibraryCardVector.png" alt="library card">
          </a>
       </section>
    </a>
</li>

<div class="popUp">
  <div>
    <div id="popUpClose"> <button type="button" class="btn">X</button></div>    
  </div>
  <div id="moreInfo">
    <!--WILL BE FILLED IN WITH <section class="hide"> DATA ABOVE-->
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a.popUpTrigger').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    if ($('.selected')) {
      let messageArea = $('.selected > section.hide');
      let strippedMessage = messageArea.text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/\s/g, "");
      let fullMessage = messageArea.html();

      if (strippedMessage === "") {
        alert("Sorry that page isn't available right now.");
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $('.popUp').css('display', 'block');
        $('.popUp #moreInfo').html(fullMessage);
      }
    }
    $('.popUp #popUpClose').on('click', function() {
      $('.popUpTrigger').removeClass('selected');
      $('.popUp').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: `if ($('.selected')) {` is wrong, jQuery object is always truthy

Comment: You can not have an anchor inside of an anchor. It is invalid HTML. SO the browser rewrites it so it is valid. So you have to rethink how you write your HTML>

Answer (score 0):

I removed the children from your anchor, and instead used `NEXT`. Also your if statement was not needed. I left .selected in the code just in case you wanted to style the anchor when clicked.

```js
$('a.popUpTrigger').on('click', function() {
    $('a.popUpTrigger').removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    
      let messageArea = $(this).next("section");
      let strippedMessage = messageArea.text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/\s/g, "");
      let fullMessage = messageArea.html();

      if (strippedMessage === "") {
        alert("Sorry that page isn't available right now.");
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $('.popUp').css('display', 'block');
        $('.popUp #moreInfo').html(fullMessage);
      }
    
    $('.popUp #popUpClose').on('click', function() {
      $('.popUpTrigger').removeClass('selected');
      $('.popUp').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

```css
.selected{color:red;}
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="card">
   <a class="popUpTrigger" href="#">
      Get a Library Card </a>

      <section class="hide">
          <h6> How to Obtain a Library Card:</h6>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <p> Additional Info </p>
          <a href="https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/858998_1fae2b5d06fa41a3ba3fcb493b349d19.pdf">
             <img src="imgs/LibraryCardVector.png" alt="library card">
          </a>
       </section>
   
</li>

<div class="popUp">
  <div>
    <div id="popUpClose"> <button type="button" class="btn">X</button></div>    
  </div>
  <div id="moreInfo">
    <!--WILL BE FILLED IN WITH <section class="hide"> DATA ABOVE-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code

```
<a href="#">
  <a href="#"></a>
</a>
```

It is not valid to have nested anchors in HTML. So the browser breaks it up when it renders. That is why you are seeing it act weird.

You will need to stick the pop up code outside of the element.

```
<a class="popUpTrigger" href="#">
   Get a Library Card
</a>
<section class="hide">
  <p>Foo</p>
  <a href="#">Bar</a>
</section>
```

and reference it with next()

```
$(".popUpTrigger").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var anchor = $(this);
  anchor.next('section').toggleClass("hide");
});
```